# RCP headless application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, headless

I have an RCP headless application. When running it, some errors can occur. I want to display them into the same cmd.exe from which I run the application. I search the internet but I couldn't find any solution, do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider this: If someone texted you "My car won't start.  How can I fix it?", would you be able to help?  StackOverflow is not a help forum. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Have you tried stderr? Or using a Java logger with a java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler?

Comment: @JimGarrison The question is clear to me and I also have nothing found about this in the documentation. Therefore, I think this is a valid question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose there is on Windows the **executable `eclipsec`**. The `c` at the end means *console*.

When you create an RCP application you will get two executables on Windows, `<my-application>.exe` and `eclipsec.exe`. If you have a headless application to be run on the command line only (as in your case), delete `<my-application>.exe` and rename `eclipsec.exe` to `<my-application>.exe`.

See also [this mailing list post](https://www.eclipse.org//lists/eclipse-dev/msg07752.html).

Comment: That might work, but I also need UI application aswell. When I run in headless mode I execute a command like:  <my-application>.exe -runInHeadLessMode + other arguments. I was wondering if there is other way than using eclipsec.exe

Comment: As far as I know there is no other way and no other reason why `eclipsec.exe` exists.